# httpget not working past "execute"

Tags: java, android, json, http-get

my program is supposed to go to a website and depending on the id(4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b), it will get a json string. For some reason, this program will not go past the client.execute line and throws an IOException. This function works for my other programs that need to extract information from a website. If you go to https://iphone-radar.com/accounts/4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b you can see the type of line I want to copy. Here is my code, I hope you can help me find out why this is happening. Thank you.

```
public String getText(String uri) {
        HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://iphone-radar.com/accounts/4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b");

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            String response_str = client1.execute(request, responseHandler);
            return response_str;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";

        }
    }
```

Comment: And what does e.printStackTrace() print? The message of the exception is, most of the time, an indication of what's wrong.

Comment: responseHandler is imported import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler; e has value javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this exception is about untrusted certificate. This will happen when you're trying to access a HTTPS with an expired certificate, or a self-signed certificate. On a browser, a popup window will show asking us whether to trust or not. In an application's process then we need to add some codes to ignore the untrusted SSL certificate, or to update the JVM certificates so that it recognizes the certificate.

Reference: [Disabling Certificate Validation in an HTTP Connection](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html)

Comment: I tried disabling the certificate validation but its still giving me the same error. As a side note when I type in the website I receive no pop up window

Comment: Really guys, stop telling people to disable SSL validation. That is a really bad idea: there is no point in using encryption if you cannot be sure who you are talking to.

Comment: But he could also update the certificates accordingly so that the SSL is recognized. For development server I guess it's OK to disable SSL validation, what do you say?

Comment: Maybe it's only my antivirus fault however the site under the link that you post has a virus.

Comment: The referenced URL doesn't seem to be going to a valid site.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely provide the stacktrace to be sure, but most probably your phone doesn't trust the CA that issued iphone-radar.com's SSL certificate: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US. (it's not in Gingerbread's trust store)

Search SO to find how to add this certificate to your trust store, there are multiple posts about this.

Comment: How can I check which certificate I need to add. Thanks

Comment: Open the site with your browser and click on the padlock icon on the status bar (IE and Chrome). Look for the issuing CA, Geo Trust Global CA. You can download (and verify the fingerprint matches) from GeoTrust's resources page: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/